# Third Parameter in Array Formula to check for highest(max) occurence but only if the other conditions are true first

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[Ok, this is the updated link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Dl4E6G6rrDoyB5mIRvWZM5n-Nds9xZMjP9fuU-BECPU/edit?usp=sharing)[image]I have multiple criteria to look through in my arrayformula(index(match())). The first two are simple as they reference the row the formula is calculating on. The last conditional I have is to find the highest occurrence in a given range, but ONLY if the other conditions are met...something like a filtered maxifs..any ideas?

Here is my code in column P `=iferror(ArrayFormula(index($F:$F,match(1,("Fee Taken"=$C:$C)*(H12=$H:$H)(maxifs($M:$M,$H:$H,H2,$C:$C,"Fee Taken"),0))),""))`

The result that I would like is to return from column F if the name matches that rows name, the transaction type is "Fee Taken" from column C, and THEN if those conditions are true I want it to find the max value from column M based on those two criterias and return the column F value for that max value row..

Ive attached some pictues to show my data.

The last part of the Match function where I have the Maxifs equaling to eachother is where I am confused; my thoughts were to see if the maxifs for the item in Column "M" can be used as a criteria..but I do not think so....I only want the highest occurence F:F if both conditions are met and it is the highest value for both those criteria in column M..

Please let me know if you need anymore info..Thanks![[image]

Comment: Remove sensitive data and share your sheet.

Comment: Done! Let me know if there is anything else.

Comment: Your sheet is not accessible.

Comment: Ok I changed the settings to be able to view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working formula will be:

```
=ArrayFormula(index($F:$F,match(1,--(M:M=(maxifs($M:$M,$H:$H,H2,$C:$C,"Fee Taken"))),0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this does indeed! Thank you @<basic>

Comment: Formulated an answer using indirect and address instead of index but this is way better. +1